# What is the meaning of '(?i)password' in python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

Pexpect can be used to automate tasks in python (does not need TCL to be installed). One of the simplest routines of this class is the 'run()' routine. It accepts a dictionary of expected question patterns as keys and the responses as values. For example

pexpect.run ('scp foo myname@host.example.com:.', events={'(?i)password': mypassword})

I know that usually '?' is used to indicate 0 or 1 occurrences of previous literal in the string (for regular expressions that is). However, over here, this does not seem to be the meaning.

Can experts comment on what is it?

Answer (score 10):

https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

> (?...)    This is an extension
>   notation (a "?" following a "(" is not
>   meaningful otherwise). The first
>   character after the "?" determines
>   what the meaning and further syntax of
>   the construct is. Extensions usually
>   do not create a new group;
>   (?P...) is the only exception to
>   this rule. Following are the currently
>   supported extensions.
>
> (?iLmsux)    (One or more letters from
>   the set "i", "L", "m", "s", "u", "x".)
>   The group matches the empty string;
>   the letters set the corresponding
>   flags (re.I, re.L, re.M, re.S, re.U,
>   re.X) for the entire regular
>   expression. This is useful if you wish
>   to include the flags as part of the
>   regular expression, instead of passing
>   a flag argument to the compile()
>   function.
>
> Note that the (?x) flag changes how
>   the expression is parsed. It should be
>   used first in the expression string,
>   or after one or more whitespace
>   characters. If there are
>   non-whitespace characters before the
>   flag, the results are undefined.

So in this case the string is a regular expression, and is set to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 6):

This is an extension in the regular expression syntax in the re module of Python. The "i" means "ignore case". This means a case insensitive search for "password" is done.

from https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

> (?iLmsux)
>   (One or more letters from the set "i", "L", "m", "s", "u", "x".) The
>   group matches the empty string; the
>   letters set the corresponding flags
>   (re.I, re.L, re.M, re.S, re.U, re.X)
>   for the entire regular expression.
>   This is useful if you wish to include
>   the flags as part of the regular
>   expression, instead of passing a flag
>   argument to the compile() function.
>
> Note that the (?x) flag changes how the expression is parsed. It
>   should be used first in the expression
>   string, or after one or more
>   whitespace characters. If there are
>   non-whitespace characters before the
>   flag, the results are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms the `(?i)` means ignore case (meaning it matches any case: lower, upper, title... case).

**Note:**
From Python 3.6, flags has to be at the begining of the expression else you will get a `deprecatingWarning` .